# Can you add product to Wishlist to Cart from Email using AMP for Email

Tags: amp-html, amp-form, amp-email

Is it possible using "AMP for Email" code that can give the user the ability to add products to wishlist or to cart?

Comment: You can try this approach from this [blogpost](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/e-commerce/product_page/?referrer=ampbyexample.com) where `add-to-cart` action is implemented using `amp-form` and share using [`amp-social-share`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-social-share?format=websites). Pressing the `ADD TO CART` button adds the product to a shopping cart page using the properties you have selected.

Comment: I will post this as an answer. Kindly accept if this will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach from this [blogpost](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/e-commerce/product_page/?referrer=ampbyexample.com) where `add-to-cart` action is implemented using `amp-form` and share using [`amp-social-share`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-social-share?format=websites). Pressing the `ADD TO CART` button adds the product to a shopping cart page using the properties you have selected.